# msysgit stopped asking for a password

Tags: ssh, git

I have a remote GIT repository (ubuntu) and am working locally on a windows 7. I had this working nicely, and setup SSH keys. At some point in this process I seem to have disabled GIT/msysgit asking for passwords. I now have a new remote git repo (on ubuntu) without keys setup and it wont ask me for my password. I tried

`git clone ssh://<user>:<pass>@<ip>:<myport>/mygitrepopath`

and it doesnt work either. But I can use putty with the same credentials to log in.

**Edit**

To setup the keys, I generated the public/private keys with putty, and added the appropriate ones to the server and into pageant. I dont remember if I took any other steps :(

this is the message I get

```
Cloning into 'myhub'...
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa blhablhablhjah
Connection abandoned.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Explain the steps you took in making the authentication work with keys. You may have hit some check box "keys only".

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can't remember, I figured that was the issue but couldnt find where. I will update question with details

Comment: Certainly looks from the error like the connection is abandoned on account of not having the server's host key cached in the registry. Have you tried correcting that error??

Comment: Yeah, it is trying to use a key. But I didnt create a key for it, I didnt for other repos...

Comment: *Host key*, SSH doesn't work without them. They're created automatically by sshd normally. Apparently it isn't in your registry. I'm not sure what ssh client git is using, but it looks like that client is rejecting the connection because it doesn't recognize the server your trying to connect to. Putty you say is working, and unless you're getting host key errors there too, Putty has the host key cached and is verifying it silently each time you connect. I don't use git, I use HG, but either way if you're a Putty user you should configure it for `plink` to avoid these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check if ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/known_hosts are writable.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed using PuTTY as your SSH provider, try these troubleshooting steps:

1. Start PuTTY
2. Connect to your git host:

   ssh user@ip -p port
3. Confirm the host's signature/fingerprint
4. Cancel the connection (CTRL-C)
5. Done. git should be able to perform all operations regardless of shell now (regular Windows command prompt, msysgit, or cygwin)

(from http://drupal.org/node/1027094)